# Modal dialogs causing UI automation to hang

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm trying to implement UI automation in a WPF application but whenever a modal dialog appears the UI automation will hang until the dialog is manually closed.

So far I've tried using a second thread to close the dialog box, setting the application to use MTA threads, using RaiseEvent to raise the Button.ClickEvent on the button to close the dialog, and using sendinput to send a keypress to the dialog.
None of these methods are working and I haven't found any other workarounds to try.

Does anyone know of any possible solutions?

Comment: When you say "implement", do you mean that you are writing code that's using UI Automation to automate a control, or that you are adding UI Automation support to an app that you own? (ie an app where you are implementing the IInvokeProvider interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give ChildWindow a shot:
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow&referringTitle=Home

Comment: I just tested this on a few of the dialogs that were causing problems and this seems to have fixed the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you guess why using that library helped? Is the `InvokePattern` implemented differently in the toolkit? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hold the UI is definition and purpose of a modal dialog.   If you don't want to hold the UI then you want a modeLESS dialog.  The UI is not hanging.  The modal dialog is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: The OP is not asking why the modal dialog is blocking the UI, but why the dialog is blocking the automation.